# Rails with Alchemy - properly set Cache-Control header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-caching, alchemy-cms

I have an app with Devise and Alchemy CMS and when I sign in, the button Login should change to Logout but it doesn't. I think that HTTP caching is enabled. If I logout, I get redirected to the home page and in the request header I can see this:

#### /users/sign_out

```
Status Code: 302
cache-control:no-cache
```

but if I go to another page the button still says "Logout".
If I refresh the home page I see this in the header:

#### /

```
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200  (from disk cache)
cache-control:public
last-modified:Mon, 17 Dec 2018 19:32:08 GMT
```

If I login and go to another page the button says Login. In the header I see this:

#### /some/other/url

```
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200  (from disk cache)
cache-control:public
last-modified:Mon, 17 Dec 2018 19:32:08 GMT
```

Is there a way I could fix that?

Comment: I've upgraded t0 4.0-stable which add `must-revalidate` to the header but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to upgrade to 4.0-stable which adds `must_revalidate` to the headers and overwrite `render_fresh_page?` method https://github.com/AlchemyCMS/alchemy_cms/blob/4.0-stable/app/controllers/alchemy/pages_controller.rb#L192

to look like this:

#### app/controllers/alchemy/pages_controller_extension.rb

```
Alchemy::PagesController.class_eval do
  def render_fresh_page?
    flash.present? || !@page.cache_page? || stale?(etag: page_etag,
      last_modified: @page.published_at,
      public: !@page.restricted,
      template: 'pages/show')
  end
end
```